# Saving multiple files on Colab - cp: cannot stat 'path': No such file or directory

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

I trained several models using Keras on Google Colab and I want to save them to my Drive.
All files are '.h5' files.

First, I mounted my drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then I tried to save the models using

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/content/")
for file in glob.glob("*.h5"):
    path = "/content/"+file
    !cp -r path "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models"
```

But I keep getting this error:

> cp: cannot stat 'path': No such file or directory

I tried using `from pathlib import Path` like this

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob, os
os.chdir("/content/")
for file in glob.glob("*.h5"):
    path = "/content/"+file
    !cp -r Path(path) "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models"
```

But it did not work and I got this error

> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /bin/bash: -c: line 0:` cp -r Path(path) "/content/gdrive/My
> Drive/models"'

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try add curly braces on the variable, here is path, and remove the double quotes on the destination path, so the final command is `!cp -r {path} /content/gdrive/My Drive/models`

Answer (score 0):

i used another package called shutil it's efficient for doing this task.

`import shutil`
`shutil.copy(file_source_path, file_dest_path`